# What to do with "release" from unwrapResumable?

Tags: haskell, conduit, haskell-wai

I wrote a [simple Wai-to-uwsgi proxy](http://hpaste.org/75713), but in doing so, I had to use `unwrapResumable`.  That gives an unwrapped `Pipe` and a "release" function that needs to be called eventually.  The release function's type is `ResourceT IO ()`, and I think I want to register it with my current resource, but to do that I'd need the release to just be `IO ()`.  What should I be doing with the release function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The release action should already be registered with your `ResourceT`. In proper `conduit` code, there are two different ways of taking care of resource cleanup:

- Within the `Pipe` itself. This cleanup will be called as early as possible, but is not exception safe.
- From `ResourceT`. This is exception safe, but may be delayed.

The cleanup action provided by `unwrapResumable` is allowing you to reclaim the "early as possible" aspect. But if you'd just be calling the cleanup outside of the `ResourceT` block, there's no need to worry about it anyway.